# Is it possible to reduce an if_else statement to a single line code

Tags: c, if-statement

I wonder if I can reduce the number of lines of the following code to a single one?

```c
if (a > (b+10))
{
    value = 1;
}
else
{
    value = 0;
}
```

Comment: `value = (a > (b+10)) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Fir very simple cases, you can use the *conditional* or *ternary* expression.

Comment: With all this said, *why* do you want to "reduce" it? If it's just as simple as shown in your question then yes you can use the conditional expression as shown. But if you have more complex code, that will very quickly become very tedious, hard to read and follow, and therefore also to maintain. And don't think that it will make your program "quicker", because it won't.

Comment: If you aim simply for reducing number of lines something is wrong. What problem do you want to solve with that?

Comment: Pure technically, you can write the complete selection statement as a single line. :-P

Comment: The only things that requires a line break in a C source file are pre-processing directives (and the last line of the file), and eventually when you have to comply to your implementation line length limit.

Comment: @Jay: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 4):

For booleans (true, false) just do:

```
bool value = a > b + 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary operator:

```c
value = (a > (b+10)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using ternary operator.

Syntax:

```
var = (condition) ? (expression1 if condition is true) : (expression2 if condition is false);
```

Your example:

```
value = (a > (b+10)) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case there are two options:

- ternary operator
- using the boolean value

## Ternary operator

The ternary operator can substitute very simple **if-else** conditions such as:

```c
value = (a > (b+10)) ? 1 : 0;
```

## Boolean value

Since your condition is attributing the value of 1 or 0 you can simply use the condition evalution. In **c** when you evaluate a condition it returns an integer between 1 and 0. Which is exactly your objective, making the above expression even simpler.

```c
value = (a > (b+10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the number of lines is easy: you can use a different brace style:

```
    if (a > (b+10)) {
        value = 1;
    } else {
        value = 0;
    }
```

You can use single statements instead of blocks:

```
    if (a > (b+10))
        value = 1;
    else
        value = 0;
```

You can cram the `if` statement on a single line (with or without curly braces):

```
    if (a > (b+10)) { value = 1; } else { value = 0; }

    if (a > (b+10)) value = 1; else value = 0;
```

You can further simplify using the ternary operator:

```
    value = (a > (b+10)) ? 1 : 0;
```

You can also remove redundant parentheses:

```
    value = a > b + 10 ? 1 : 0;
```

Finally, since comparisons in C evaluate to `int` values `1` or `0`, the above expression is still fully redundant, so you could simply write:

```
    value = a > b + 10;
```

Note that `value` does not need to have type `bool` for its value to be `1` or `0` in this case, but typing it as `bool` may help the reader better understand the code.